# How can I make that the images a) don't have space between them and b) don't interfere with the text?

Tags: graphics, latextools

I'm trying to do a figure like the one below in LaTeX:

[image: image that I want to do]

However, I don't know how to make it so they don't have space between them. Also, they start to interfere with the text and the document doesn't have sense any more. I'm using the next code for all the images.

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
  \subfloat[M20]{
   \label{f: M20}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{M20}}
  \subfloat[M14]{
   \label{f:M14}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{M14}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
  \subfloat[M23]{
   \label{f: M23}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{M23}}
  \subfloat[M5]{
   \label{f:M5}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{M5}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: Is there a direct connection between the code and images you posted? Please clarify.

Comment: the Image is only an example of how I want my work to be, and the code is the one I'm using

Comment: Using multiple [p] floats adds a `\floatsep` gap between them.  You could combine them manually, reduce `\floatsep` or add `\vspace*{-\floatsep}` inisde the floats.  BTW, combining them will still add a `\lineskip`  (1pt) gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer as in one of my PhD reports, I needed a similar format as the image you put in (one page at least) so I already had a similar template ready:

[image]

As you have not provided much detail (as @Mico commented), this answer will probably be bested by others when more details are given but it could help get you started (assuming your page is portrait and not landscape, assuming you don't want 16 subfigures in one long figure).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,
            listformat=simple,
            ]{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % For graphics
\usepackage{lipsum}     % For dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.} % Change the captions
        \label{fig:1a}          % Change the labels
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption.}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \caption{Main test caption.}
    \label{fig:lefy}
\end{figure*}

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Without the captions:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,
                listformat=simple,
                ]{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx} % For graphics
\usepackage{lipsum}     % For dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\[1.2ex]
    \caption{Main test caption.}
    \label{fig:lefy}
\end{figure*}

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was what I needed, you helped me a lot and sorry if I lacked details, but the code helped me a lot

Comment: No problem, just in the future help us help you as we didnt know if you wanted 16 figures haha, glad it helped!